# Ubuntu USB Boot Memory Stick - Cursor Black Screen

Tags: live-usb

I created Ubuntu 13.10 Live USB stick using UNetbootin.

Upon plug into a Dell laptop and boot with USB option, all i have is a blank screen with a blinking cursor infinitely.

What can I do to get it working?

Comment: check what it is going in the background.
Use alt+tab few times to know where it is stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

Is UEFI / Secure Boot enabled? That might mess with things, lots of documentation on it though, so it might be a good idea to google about Ubuntu and UEFI.

Barring that:
As soon as Ubuntu starts booting, so after the boot menu, hit Escape a couple of times.

This should make the purple-ish background color change to black and you should see what's going on "under the hood" and should be able to tell where it's getting hung up.

I've had bad luck installing 13.10 from a USB stick, but it always booted into Live mode without issues.
You might check the MD5 hash for the file you downloaded, see if it didn't get corrupted.

Good luck